# Drupal 7 - exposed filter - full text search

Tags: drupal, full-text-search, drupal-views

I'm using Drupal 7 with Views 3. I created an exposed filter for text field. 
In exposed filter options from Operator dropdown I selected `Contains`, so query goes like this:

`SELECT ... WHERE some_field LIKE...`

Is it possible to change it simply (plugin/module/some options/etc) to mysql fulltext search?

Any tip would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have manage it:)

In `views_query_alter` hook in my view I switch the condition like this:

```
unset($query->where[1]['conditions'][0]);
$query->add_where_expression('AND', MATCH(field_data_field_searchable.field_searchable_value) AGAINST ('{$searchable_value}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```